# Should I re-use a database connection or create new collections while closing old ones? social media

Tags: mysql, connections, connection-pooling

this is for a social media with constant requests for new posts, checking is someone is following, getting comments, ect.

i wont specify which language as it doesnt really matter but, currently in my code i

- make connection
- get/do what i want
- close

and then repeat

instead should I use a system where i make a connection, and then do thinsg from that while sometimes running an update?

thanks!

Comment: "i wont specify which language as it doesnt really matter" it does, as does which driver you are using.

Comment: @Charlieface the question was just should i use connection pooling or not lol

Comment: You didn't mention pooling anywhere in the question (apart from in a tag), maybe make that clear?

Comment: good point, the question was is there a better way than just constantly opening and closing the connection. still doesnt matter which language im using. "is this efficient or not", to dumb it down i guess lol.

Comment: That is the recommended way, there is nothing inefficient about it. Connection pooling sorts everything out, just make sure to open *and* close (in a `finally` `using` whatever) your connection object so that the physical connection gets released to the pool.

Comment: "*doesnt matter which language im using*" - What an odd thing to be adamant about. To answer the question "*should you use connection pooling*" will depend on if you're already using it, which you don't seem to realize that you might be with your current process. As Charlieface mentioned, this **will** depend on what technologies you're using.

Comment: @J.D. if im asking the question "should i be using pooling or not" doesn't depend on the language, or if im already using it. its a yes or no question lol. i know my current setup is not using it. there is no need to say that, as the question is, "is there a more efficient way to do this". so the answer would be "yes, pooling is better to use". thats it lmao

Comment: @CorieLeClair "*the question is, "is there a more efficient way to do this". so the answer would be "yes, pooling is better to use"*" - This is what I'm simply trying to say, we can't tell you if your process can be more efficient if we don't know if you're using connection pooling already or not, which would depend on which technologies you're using. But you haven't really clearly mentioned that you aren't using connection pooling already until your last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"do things from that connection while sometimes running an update" is not possible, as each session (connection) can only execute one SQL statement at a time. However, opening and closing connections every time you want something done is also a bad idea, because the overhead of establishing a connection is significant, especially for short transactions.

What you *want* to do is maintain a *connection pool*, whereas a pre-configured number of connections is created upon the application startup and then reused. This solves two problems: avoids the overhead of establishing connections frequently, and allows you to limit the number of open database connections, reducing the resource usage on the database server,  while supporting a potentially large number of clients. The latter is possible, because in practice not all clients require the use of a connection at the same time.

Most programming frameworks support connection pooling.

Comment: alright thank you. im running a social media for a learning/school project so this sounds like what I should do. I'm running is with python + flask so its already a bit slower than other platforms. thank you! you win the solution

Comment: "Most programming frameworks support connection pooling" *by default*, therefore it's always worthwhile to just close and reopen the connection. This keeps pressure on the server to a minimum

Comment: @Charlieface so youre saying youd prefer to just continue to close and open connections instead of pooling?

Comment: @CorieLeClair No, pooling is *automatic* in most drivers unless you switch it off, so actually closing and opening the connections doesn't do anything except release the internal conenction back to the pool. If you *don't* close it you run into more problems, because the connection is not released back to the pool.

Comment: I would be wary of that "by default" comment, because it's not always true. You better check your framework docs about that. Some rely on the driver for pooling, and not all drivers do that. Besides, closing a pooled connection just returns it to the pool, so in no way it affects the "pressure on the server".

Answer (score 0):

There is rarely any justification for more than one Connect during the execution of a program.

MySQL is happy to have hundreds of "Sleeping" connections for long-running programs that only sporadically do some action.

Here's two use cases involving PHP:

For a webpage using PHP under Apache, open *one* connection near the beginning of the script; disconnect it at the end (or let it automatically close when the PHP script is over.  A webpage that runs for more than a few seconds is problematic for reasons other than "connections".

It's the same for an AJAX call back to a PHP script.  It requires a CONNECT + action (such as UPDATE) + DISCONNECT (explicit or implicit).  If there is any pooling, it is not handled by the PHP script.

Comment: In a PHP script maybe, but most applications can have multiple points where a connection is necessary, and keeping all those connectons open *is* a burden on the server. Connection pooling was invented for a reason, and is automatic, you just need to make sure to use by closing your connection object (which releases the internal connection back to the pool).

Comment: @Charlieface - If it is a single thread in a single process, have only one connection for all the activity.  Please provide more detail on "multiple points".

Comment: Like I said: true for a simple PHP script which runs once per request, not common with ASP.NET or any other large monolithic application, or any application where designs like Repository pattern is implemented. And it's a bit of a downside for PHP that connection pooling is effectively impossible across requests  (because of the way TCP sockets work) unless the driver implements it out of process.